# Saving backslash-escaped characters to variable in bash

Tags: bash, escaping

I've just written a bash script that takes some info from the mysql database and reads it line by line, extracting tab-separated columns into separate variables, something like this:

```
oldifs=$IFS

result=result.txt
$mysql -e "SELECT id,foo,bar,baz FROM $db.$table" -u $user --password=$pass -h $server > $result

cat $result | grep -e ^[0-9].*$ | while IFS=$'\t' read id foo bar baz
do
    # some code
done

IFS=$oldifs
```

Now, while this works OK and I'm satisfied with the result (especially since I'm going to move the query t oanother script and let cron regenerate the result.txt file contents once a week or so, since I'm dealing with a table that changes maybe once or twice a year), I'm curious about the possibility of putting the query's result in a variable instead of a file.

I have noticed that in order to echo out backslash-excaped characters, I need to tell the command explicitly to interpret such characters as special chars:

```
echo -e "some\tstring\n"
```

But, being a bash noob that I am, I have no idea how to place the backslash escaped characters (the tabs and newlines from the query) inside a variable and just work with it the same way I'm working with the external file (just changing the `cat` with `echo -e`). I tried this:

```
result=`$mysql -e "SELECT id,foo,bar,baz FROM $db.$table" -u $user --password=$pass -h $server`
```

but the backslash escaped characters are converted into spaces this way :(. How can I make it work?

Comment: There's no need to save and restore the value of `IFS` since setting it in the way you have done makes the scope of the change local to `read`. You don't need the temporary file, you could pipe the output of the `mysql` command (which won't work with the leading dollar sign, by the way) directly into `grep`. If you do want the temporary file for some reason, there's no need to use `cat` since `grep` will accept the filename as an argument.

Comment: @Dennis, `$mysql` is a variable equal to the result of `which mysql`, so it most certainly works :). I didn't quote the entire script because it's 80 lines long and irrelevant to the question. I need a temporary storage because I loop through the query's results twice. Launching it twice just to pipe it to `grep` seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: Oh, @Dennis, the `IFS` and `cat`/`grep` tips are much appreciated. My script has just lost some complexity ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to set double quotes around `$result` - thus `echo -e "$result"`?

Comment: Hm, indeed, I haven't tried this. I'll check when I'm back at the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: What do you know, it worked. Come to think of it, it's sort of logical that backslash-escaped chars only take effect when quoted. Thanks for the simple solution, mate.

Answer (score 2):

To get the output of a command, use `$(...)`. To avoid wordsplitting and other bash processing you will need to quote. Single quotes (`'$(...)'`) will not work as the quoting is too strong.

Note that once the output is in your variable, you will probably need to (double) quote it wherever you use it if you need to preserve anything that's in `$IFS`.

```
$ listing="$(ls -l)"
$ echo "$listing"
```

Comment: Ah, you just made me notice an error in my example code, I swapped the positions of `while` and `read`. I edited that. Anyway, you mean that if I do `result="$($mysql ...)"`, `result` will hold all the `\t` and `\n` characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
% awk '/^[0-9]/ { print $2, $3, $4, $5 }' <<SQL | set -- - 
> $("${mysql}" -e "SELECT id,foo,bar,baz FROM $db.$table" -u $user --password=$pass -h $server)
> SQL
% printf '%s\t' "${@}"
<id>    <foo>    <bar>    <baz>
```

You might get some use out of this. The `heredoc` should obviate any escaping issues, `awk` will separate on tabs by default, and `set` accepts the input as a builtin `argv` array. `printf` isn't necessary, but it's better than `echo` - especially when working with escape characters.

You could also use `read` as you did above - but to better handle backslashes use the `-r` argument if you go that route. The above method would work best as a function and you could then iterate over your variables with `shift` and similar.

-Mike